# REDIS Desktop Manager error

Tags: spring, caching, redis, jedis

Anyone ever experienced "Can not load key value. Key was removed or redis-server went away." error when viewing a key in Redis Desktop Manager? I am using Jedis as the client to push data to Redis server. I can see (from the terminal, MONITOR command) that the cache is being populated though. And when I retrieve data, I am 100% sure I am getting the data from the cache and not from database. Any input is appreciated. I am new to Redis btw.  Thanks!

Comment: can you use retrieve your value in the console redis-cli ?  If so, check the config of your desktop manager. Maybe you have a firewall issue

Comment: hi @Pixou yes, I can retrieve using console redis-cli. I don't get the error when I push using cli though. The problem happens only when the cache element is pushed via Jedis.

Comment: @rms24601 I have the same issue, did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by disabling SSH tunneling on the Redis desktop manager connection.